# Error connecting MATLAB to SQLServer

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, matlab, jdbc

First, I have downloaded microsoft jdbc driver(sqljdbc42.jar) for Sqlserver and added it to path. And I can use it to connect to my local MySQL database using the following codes:

```
database('**','**','**','com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/')
```

But I cannot connect to a remote SQLServer with error message: Unable to find JDBC driver. The codes are:

```
database('**','**','**','com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver','jdbc:sqlserver://**')
```

Comment: You are saying that you are using a microsoft jdbc driver to connect to a mysql database but in your query you are using a mysql driver. Please update your question so it makes sense

Comment: _"added it to path"_, you should add it to the class path, not the path. Please be precise in your question.